# How to plot this in R?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I want to plot `speed` vs `age`. Here's the data:

```
Speed   Age
15      <18
30      18-25
40      26-40
32      40+
```

How do I plot this as a scatter plot in R? I don't know how to do ranges. This is what I have so far.

```
speed<-c(15,30,40,32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ggplot2`:

```
# Make a data frame
df <- data.frame(Speed = c(15, 30, 40, 32), 
                 Age = factor(c("<18", "18-25", "26-40", "40+")))

require(ggplot2)
# Use the geom_point geom
ggplot(df, aes(Speed, Age)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `plot(x, y)`. Check out http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html